# Connecting devices with different logic levels

Tags: power-supply, level-shifting

The following figure is taken from [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/65) link, where the author explains how NOT to connect devices having different logic levels

[image]

He says that:

> Directly connecting the devices together (see above) will overstress
>   the 3.3V device and eventually lead to device failure.

Can somebody explain me why this overstress will happen and what makes the device failure?

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you exceed the limits listed in the datasheet you don't know what the device might do.  5 V is simply out of spec for the 3.3 V device, so it could fail, get hot, not work right, vanish into a greasy cloud of gray smoke, or whatever.

What actually happens in many ICs is that there are protection diodes from external pins to the internal power and ground nets.  By forcing a pin to a higher voltage than the chip's supply voltage, the diode from the pin to the power net will conduct.  This can cause currents in places there aren't intended to be currents during normal operation.  That can cause all kinds of off-spec behavior.  If this current exists while the power is coming up, it could even make the whole die go into SCR latching mode.

Of course the above was only one explanation of what happens in some ICs.  When the spec says the maximum pin voltage is 3.3 V, you should not apply more than 3.3 V and not assume you know what might happen if you violate this spec.

Some 3.3 V chips have "5 V tolerant" inputs.  In that case the chips contains additional circuitry so that 5 V on the pin won't hurt anything and will be interpreted as a normal digital high level.  For such inputs, it is fine to drive them directly from the output of 5 V logic.  But, this is only valid if the datasheet explicitly says it's OK.  Usually the valid voltage levels for digital inputs is well specified in the datasheet.  Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

When the 5V device drives 5V signals to the 3.3V device, the 3.3V device is receiving potentially higher voltages that what it expects. Parasitic diodes on input lines in the 3.3V device will become forward biased and route the incoming 5V (via a diode drop) onto the local 3.3V rail and the device may become damaged either by supply overstress or by excessive current through the diodes.

Not all 3.3V devices are like this. Some are what is known as "5V tolerant".

Comment: Need not just be *parasitic diodes* - by-design clamping diodes on chip are pretty common.

Answer (score 0):

While not a complete answer:

Most 3.3v devices (may) have a clamping diode built in on input ports. These diodes will "step down" over-voltage to a safe value. The problem with this is - the excess voltage is dissipated as heat. Your 3.3v device could burn out eventually (hence, stressed).

In the case of devices NOT having an internal clamping diode, shoving 5 Volts into a 3.3v device is virtually guaranteed to blow something.

That same linked page shows alternatives for level shifting. The simple diode/pull-up resistor combo is a nifty, cheap, and highly effective solution for many setups.